# Django using a ManytoMany as a Foreign Key

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm trying to use a many to many relation as a foreign key for another table, but I'm not sure if this is possible.Consider the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Protocol(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attributes=models.ManyToManyField(Attribute,db_table='protocol_attribute')

class Device(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    id_protocol=models.ForeignKey(Protocol)

class DeviceValues(models.Model):
    id_device=models.ForeignKey(Device)
    id_protocol_attribute=models.ForeignKey(Protocol.attributes)
    value=models.IntegerField()
```

When I try to validate this model I receive the following error:

```
First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

I know I am not using a model or a model name as the first parameter, but how can I reference as a foreign key the join table that Django will automatically create that handles the mapping between Protocol and Attributes?

A possible workaround could be to add the protocol as a foreign key to the Attribute class and then use the attribute as a foreing key to the DeviceValue class. However, I don't want to do that because I will have protocols that will be sharing attributes. I would prefer to make the join table rather that repeating attributes for each protocol.

Any ideas will be more than welcome....thanks!!!

Alejandro

Comment: Does `Protocol.attributes.through` work?

Comment: It does!!! Originally I understood you can't add more foreign keys in the intermediate table than those involved in the m2m relation. However, I tried it and didn't complain. One thing to take into account is that it doesn't generate the UNIQUE constraint for the 3 foreign keys in the sql file, so I just had to manually add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an intermediate table, I solved it. The model ended up like this.

```
from django.db import models

class Attribute(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   unit=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Protocol(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
   attributes=models.ManyToManyField(Attribute,through='DeviceValue')

class Device(models.Model):
   serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   id_protocol=models.ForeignKey(Protocol)

class DeviceValue(models.Model):
   id_name=models.ForeignKey(Protocol)
   id_attribute=models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
   id_device=models.ForeignKey(Device)
   value=models.IntegerField()
```

One thing worth mention is that when using sqlall the UNIQUE constraint for the three foreign keys of the DeviceValue tablue was not generated, so I just added it before creating the database.