# Django - foreign key to ManyToMany (through) fails with SystemCheckError

Tags: django, django-models

Using the following relations:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    pass

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(to=Author)

class Contract(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(to=Book.authors.through, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

we are trying to have a foreign key point at the `through` model without explicitly defining it
(see also comment by Daniel Roseman in [Django using a ManytoMany as a Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719682/django-using-a-manytomany-as-a-foreign-key) )

This fails with `SystemCheckError`:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
Contract.work: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Book_authors', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

`Book.authors.through` is a model that is not abstract.

Why does it not work anymore (django 3.2)?

Comment: Just tested this on 2.2. Getting the same error when `through` is not defined for `authors`, but works if a custom `through` model is supplied. EDIT: Seems the question in the link you shared was solved by adding a custom `through` model as well.

Comment: Explicitly defining `through` has a lot of implications (admin needs inline, DRF needs extra serializer, ...) Therefore I would like to avoid that

Comment: Yes that's true though it seems using it like this will not work, even from django 2.2. Which version did it used to work for you?